# Get all product images in Magento 2 on product list page

Tags: image, magento, media, product, mage

In Magento 1 I've always used

```
$_product->getMediaGallery('images')
```

But in the source from Magento 2 I see

```
$productImage = $block->getImage($_product, $image);
echo $productImage->toHtml();
```

It's only getting the first product image.
How do I get the second or third image (not only the base one)?

GetMediaGallery function doesn't exists?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114691/magento-2-get-media-gallery-in-productlist Please look into this for right solution.

Answer (score -1):

Step 1 : open list.phtml from Your Theme\Magento_Catalog\templates\product

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
```

$_imagehelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');

Add above in your phtml file

then add below code in product loop where you want gallery images

```
<div class="left-carousel">

                   <div  class="product-small-thumbs">
                    <?php $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_product->getId());


                          $images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
                          if($images->count()>0){?>
                          <div class="carousel carousel-<?php $_product->getId()?>">


                         <?php
                          $i = 0;
                          foreach($images as $child){
                            $i++;
                            $productImage = $_imagehelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_large')
                                ->setImageFile($child->getFile())->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(TRUE)->resize(81,53)
                                ->getUrl();

                            $productImagedata = $_imagehelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_large')
                            ->setImageFile($child->getFile())->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(TRUE)->resize(285,240)
                            ->getUrl();
                            if($i==1) continue;

                            ?>
                            <div class="slide">
                             <img data-id="smallthumbs-<?php echo $_product->getId();?>" data-img="<?php echo $productImagedata; ?>" src="<?php echo $productImage; ?>"/>
                            </div>

                            <?php

                           }
                           ?>
                           </div>

                           <?php
                            }
                    ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: "Magento prohibits the direct use of the ObjectManager in your code because it hides the real dependencies of a class." https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/object-manager.html